# Format source code such that the maximum number of characters does not exceed a given limit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, formatting

Several extensions to Visual Studio like [VisualAssist](http://wholetomato.com/) or the [Visual Studio Productivity PowerTools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) support the definition of a "guideline". The "guideline" (which is the technical term used within the mentioned extensions) is a vertical line drawn into the text editor. The idea is that, e.g. in order to conform with coding styles, the source code should not exceed the "guideline".

I understand that at least the above-mentioned extensions do not provide built-in support for enforcing the policy such that the source code can (on demand, e.g. by means of a menu item or a toolbar button) be automatically re-formatted to not exceed the "guideline".

Is there any free (as in "free beer") Visual Studio extension out there that contributes a source-code formatter for this purpose?

Comment: Do you find `Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document` inadequate in this situation?

Comment: Unfortunately the built-in formatter does not enforce a maximum number of characters in a single line.

Comment: @Uwe: gotcha, I interpreted your question to mean "guideline" in a vague sense and not the physical gray line VS puts down a given column. Could you please clarify your question some?

Comment: Line length seems such a bad metric to be strictly enforced...

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Visual Studio 2010 by itself does not support said "gray line". The mentioned extensions contribute the ability to at least draw the "guideline" (which is the precise technical term used by these extension to describe the functionality) into the text editor.

Comment: @Uwe: I set mine using a registry entry.

Comment: Resharper is not free, but will limit number of characters per line